# Making a Higher Order Component to inter-operate react-relay and react-router with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router, relay

Okay, my Frankenstein monster has gotten out of control and I only have so much hair left to pull out, so any help here is appreciated.

I'm trying to get a very basic app setup working with React, React-Router, React-Relay, and Typescript. I actually have it all functioning, but it's doing so while throwing some nasty Typescript errors that I'd like to correct.

So, the basic react-router + react-relay setup mimics the official react-relay approach found here: https://medium.com/@cpojer/relay-and-routing-36b5439bad9

Unfortunately, when translating this into TypeScript and using the imported type-definitions for react-relay via typings (and, I would *very* much not have to modify the imported type definitions); `Route` has defined props and TypeScript objects to passing a `home` and `queries` prop to the `Route` component.

Apologies for just dumping my code in here, but you'll need it to fully appreciate the problem.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Router, Route, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import * as Relay from 'react-relay';
import MainApp from './components/MainApp';

const createRelayContainer: any = function createRelayContainer (Component: new() => React.Component<any, any>, props: any): JSX.Element {
  if (Relay.isContainer(Component)) {
    // construct the RelayQueryConfig from the route and the router props
    const { name, queries } = props.route;
    const { params } = props;

    return (
      <Relay.RootContainer
        Component={Component}
        renderFetched={(data: any) : any => <Component {...props} {...data} /> }
        route={{name, params, queries}}
       />
    );
  }
  return <Component {...props} />;
};

const homeQueries: any = {
  viewer: (): Relay.QLExpression => Relay.QL`
    query {
      viewer
    }`,
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router
    history={ browserHistory }
    createElement={createRelayContainer}>
    <Route>
      <Route
        name='home'
        path='/'
        component={MainApp}
        queries={homeQueries}
      />
    </Route>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('root'));
;
```

As I said, this actually functions as expected but the rub is that the react-router interface for `Route` doesn't have `name` or `queries` so TypeScript throws errors.

I'm sure there are a couple of different approaches to solving this, but I have no clue what would be best practice in this scenario.

(Some basic version info may be helpful: TypeScript 1.8.10, React 15, React-Router 2.4, React-Relay 0.8)

Answer (score 2):

Okay, the simplest answer here is to just add to the imported react-router definitions via namespace merging (I didn't know Typescript allowed you to do this).

For those who are interested, just add an `overrides.d.ts` (or whatever you want to name it) and add to the `RouteProps` interface:

```
declare namespace ReactRouter {
  interface RouteProps {
    name?: string;
    queries?: any;
  }
}
```

Honestly, there might be a more clever way to go about this whole thing, but this is the easiest and it works.

Sigh, there went hours of my life...